# InfluxDB unable to write to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, containers, influxdb, influxdb-python

I use Inflluxdb 1.6.4
I use a Python script to send a CSV file to an Influx database. The script runs without errors, and when I check the logs of the InfluxDB Kubernetes container, it shows that it receives the write requests successfully e.g.,

```
\[httpd\] 10.244.0.1 - admin \[01/Dec/2023:05:22:40 +0000\] "POST /write?db=ric_test HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" a5e794c0-9009-11ee-8523-0a4914573a6e 2245
```

However, when I check the measurements in the InfluxDB database, it shows no results.

This is my python file.

```py
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
from database import DATABASE
from configparser import ConfigParser


class INSERTDATA(DATABASE):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.config()
        self.connect()
#        self.dropdb('RIC-Test')
#        self.createdb('RIC-Test')

    def config(self):
        cfg = ConfigParser()
        cfg.read('ad_config.ini')
        for section in cfg.sections():
            if section == 'influxdb':
                self.host = cfg.get(section, "host")
                self.port = cfg.get(section, "port")
                self.user = cfg.get(section, "user")
                self.password = cfg.get(section, "password")
                self.path = cfg.get(section, "path")
                self.ssl = cfg.get(section, "ssl")
                self.dbname = cfg.get(section, "database")
                self.meas = cfg.get(section, "measurement")

    def createdb(self, dbname):
        print("Create database: " + dbname)
        self.client.create_database(dbname)
        self.client.switch_database(dbname)

    def dropdb(self, dbname):
        print("DROP database: " + dbname)
        self.client.drop_database(dbname)

    def dropmeas(self, measname):
        print("DROP MEASUREMENT: " + measname)
        self.client.query('DROP MEASUREMENT '+measname)

    def assign_timestamp(self, df):
        steps = df['measTimeStampRf'].unique()
        for timestamp in steps:
            d = df[df['measTimeStampRf'] == timestamp]
            d.index = pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(), freq='1ms', periods=len(d))
            self.client.write_points(d, self.meas)
            time.sleep(0.7)


def populatedb():
    # inintiate connection and create database UEDATA
    db = INSERTDATA()
    df = pd.read_csv('ue.csv')
    while True:
        db.assign_timestamp(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    populatedb()
```

and this is container log:

```
[httpd] 10.244.0.1 - admin [01/Dec/2023:05:27:38 +0000] "POST /write?db=RIC_Test HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" 577fe481-900a-11ee-87ed-0a4914573a6e 1708
[httpd] 10.244.0.1 - admin [01/Dec/2023:05:27:39 +0000] "POST /write?db=RIC_Testt HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" 57c2d326-900a-11ee-87ee-0a4914573a6e 2013
[httpd] 10.244.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2023:05:27:39 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "kube-probe/1.16" 57d5cabe-900a-11ee-87ef-0a4914573a6e 32
[httpd] 10.244.0.1 - admin [01/Dec/2023:05:27:39 +0000] "POST /write?db=RIC_TestHTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" 5806151c-900a-11ee-87f0-0a4914573a6e 2179
```

This is config:

```
[influxdb]
host = 10.244.0.93 
port = 8086
user = admin
password =  1234
path = 
database = RIC_Test
measurement = UEReports
ssl = False 

[features]
thpt = DRB.UEThpDl
rsrp = RF.serving.RSRP
rsrq = RF.serving.RSRQ
rssinr  = RF.serving.RSSINR
prb_usage = RRU.PrbUsedDl
ue = ue-id
anomaly = Viavi.UE.anomalies
a1_param = thp_threshold
```

This is result:

```
> USE RIC_Test


Using database RIC_Test
> SHOW MEASUREMENTS
```

Check the container log:

```
[httpd] 10.244.0.1 - admin [01/Dec/2023:05:27:38 +0000] "POST /write?db=RIC_Test HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" 577fe481-900a-11ee-87ed-0a4914573a6e 1708
[httpd] 10.244.0.1 - admin [01/Dec/2023:05:27:39 +0000] "POST /write?db=RIC_Testt HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" 57c2d326-900a-11ee-87ee-0a4914573a6e 2013
[httpd] 10.244.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2023:05:27:39 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "kube-probe/1.16" 57d5cabe-900a-11ee-87ef-0a4914573a6e 32
```

Restart InfluxDB